# package com.facebook.react.modules.storage does not exist for AsyncStorage

Tags: java, react-native, asyncstorage

`import com.facebook.react.modules.storage.ReactDatabaseSupplier;`

I'm trying to access AsyncStorage natively on Android by accessing to the **ReactDatabaseSupplier** but no luck getting the com.facebook.react.module.storage imported. I've tried a few ways like gradle clean, removed node_modules but it's still the same.

`error: package com.facebook.react.modules.storage does not exist import com.facebook.react.modules.storage.ReactDatabaseSupplier;`